# MGBox2 Shows nothing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to get [MGBox](https://github.com/JayZhao/MGBox2) to work on my app, with no use - all I see is a blank app window, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong (I even tried to translate the objective c from the DemoController that comes with it

this is the code of my controller

```
import Foundation

class MainController: UIViewController {

    var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    @IBOutlet weak var mainView: MGScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mainView.contentLayoutMode = MGLayoutGridStyle
        mainView.bottomPadding = 8

        var box: MGBox = appDelegate.client.user.getViews()
        var tablesGrid = MGBox.boxWithSize(CGSize(width: 320,height: 0)) as! MGBox
        tablesGrid.contentLayoutMode = MGLayoutGridStyle
        mainView.boxes.addObject(tablesGrid)

        var table1 = MGBox.box() as! MGBox
        tablesGrid.boxes.addObject(table1)
        table1.sizingMode = MGResizingShrinkWrap

        var table2 = MGBox.box() as! MGBox
        tablesGrid.boxes.addObject(table2)
        table2.sizingMode = MGResizingShrinkWrap

        var menu = MGTableBoxStyled.box() as! MGTableBoxStyled
        table1.boxes.addObject(menu)

        var header = MGLine.lineWithLeft("MG Demo", right: nil, size: CGSize(width: 304, height: 44)) as! MGLine
        header.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue", size:18)
        header.leftPadding = 16
        header.rightPadding = 16
        menu.topLines.addObject(header)

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked (with the debugger) to see if mainView is not nil when the view loads?

Comment: One trick I sometimes use is to set the background color of a subview to something bright (like red) to make sure that it is sitting where I think it should be sitting.

Comment: did that, it is sitting where I want it - even tried changing the controller used to the DemoViewController that comes with it, with that objective c it's working, it seems like I translated the swift wrong, just not sure how.